# Connecting to a Windows Homegroup on a non-Windows device

Tags: windows, streaming, homegroup

Is is possible to connect to a Windows Homegroup (Windows 7) from a non-Windows device? IF not, is there a different feature within Windows which would achieve something similar, or is it entirely dependent on the software being ran from the connecting device?

Basically, I've recently purchased a Western Digital Streaming Media Player which can access the internet for YouTube etc, but I was wondering if I could use it to stream files (video) straight from my PC.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A WD TV box can be connected to a pc; this is best done with a DLNA (UPnP) server, which you run on the computer. Windows media player is the standard in-built media server for windows 7; personally I have found it to be a bit temperamental, so I use the PS3 media server.

http://www.ps3mediaserver.org/

It may be called PS3, but it does work with all DLNA clients and it very reliable and simple to use. Of course you can use other servers. You may need to ensure network sharing is enabled too for the folders you wish to share, which can be found by right clicking on the folder > properties > sharing > share